# Can we check the queue depth using a scripting language?

Tags: java, perl, bash, shell, ibm-mq

Is it feasible to check queue depth(MQ) using any scripts? [No restrictions on the language]. The plan is to look at non-Java solutions.

I do understand that it is achievable in Java using MQQueueManager but that would need the usage of client API. Hence checking for any alternate options or better practices.

InquireQueue at http://www.capitalware.biz/mq_code_perl_python.html looks similar[but looks a bit outdated]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't Google give you a recent blog posting I wrote called "How to Clear a MQ Queue from a Script or Program" at http://www.capitalware.biz/rl_blog/?p=1616

Just change the MQSC "clear" command to "current depth" (CURDEPTH).
i.e.

```
DIS QL(TEST.*) CURDEPTH
```

Comment: Thanks Roger. But could we set the security exit in case of secured queues, especially when using encrypted files for authentication?(and not plain username/password). I do see we can set the latter using MQEnvironment.

Answer (score 1):

Does nobody use google anymore ?

PyMQI, an open-source Python extension for WebSphere MQ

http://metacpan.org/pod/MQSeries::Queue

my %qattr = $queue->Inquire( qw(MaxMsgLength MaxQDepth) );

Comment: Thanks Brian. But it's maybe about using the right term for search.

Comment: Um Brian, you said PyMQI yet the link you provided is to some other project. PyMQI is for Python, here's the correct link :-) http://packages.python.org/pymqi/

Answer (score 1):

The perl mqseries is very complete. Below is some sample code. (Part of the credit for the sample probably goes to someone else, but it has been floating around my drive for years.) The code connects to the queue manager specified by the command line, if not supplied, it will connect to the default queue manager. It then inquires about the queue name passed in, specifically, the current depth of that queue. This is displayed to the user. This code can easily be modified to display other queue properties. Furthermore, MQINQ can be used to inquire about the attributes of other objects, not just queues.Here is the subset sample code:

```
use MQSeries;

my $quename = $ARGV[0];
my $quemgrname = $ARGV[1];

my $Hconn = MQCONN($qmgrname, $CompCode, $Reason);
print"MQCONN reason:$Reason\n";

my $ObjDesc = { ObjectType => MQOT_Q, ObjectName => $qname };

my $Options = MQOO_INQUIRE | MQOO_SET | MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;
my $Hobj = MQOPEN($Hconn,$ObjDesc,$Options,$CompCode,$Reason);
print"MQOPEN reason:$Reason\n";

my $tst = MQINQ($Hconn,$Hobj,$CompCode,$Reason,MQIA_CURRENT_Q_DEPTH);
print"Depth of $qname is: $tst\n";

MQCLOSE($Hconn,$Hobj,$COptions,$CompCode,$Reason);
print"MQCLOSE reason:$Reason\n";
MQDISC($Hconn,$CompCode,$Reason);
print"MQDISC reason:$Reason\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are logged in using MQM user on linux and want to have a quick check on queues with messages in them .. here is a quickfix ..

```
echo "dis ql(*) CURDEPTH" | runmqsc <QMGRNAME> | grep -v '(0' | grep -v 'AMQ'
```

this will give you a command line output and you can schedule the same command in crontab if needed directly ( without having to save a script for it )

I know its not neat but may be the quickest of solutions.

Answer (score -3):

There's the many JVM based scripting/ish languages that give you access to Java classes. Some need a thin glue layer, some need nothing at all.

- Groovy
- Jython
- Scala
- Clojure
- etc.

Comment: Can the downvoter give a reason? The question is "I can do this from Java but I want to do it from a scripting language" -- these languages all answer that question.